# Need some help trying to identify an IC package for soldering

Tags: integrated-circuit

Please see the below image, it's a BCM4366 WiFi IC.

I'm looking to reflow/replace one of these ICs and trying to figure out what the package is and how best to solder a replacement. (Reball/paste/reflow etc.)

[image]

EDIT:

Should probably have provided some context.

This is for a D8500 Netgear router whereby one of the radios has failed owing to I believe cold solder joints.

I have reflow requirement and am experienced in circuitry and repair. I bought this router because it was faulty (£11 Inc p&p) with the intention of repairing it. Initially thought it was a software issue, tried various firmwares, drivers ect but the radio would not initialise.

Then attempted to reflow the IC but couldn't get enough heat into the board owing to large ground planes and not having a pre-heater at the time.

However, after letting the board cool and turning it back on, the radio did start to work for a few minutes until it disappeared.

I've got an IR Hotplate PCB heater winging it's way to me now as I could have used one with my last project so that will tackle the board heating issue and I'm hoping to just reflow the chip with plenty of flux.

However, I've also got some replacement ICs on their way (hopefully) hence asking how best to solder one of these incase I need to replace fully.

Comment: Have you tried to look in the datasheet what it says?

Comment: Unfortunately, because it's a Broadcom device, there is no public datasheet

Answer (score 0):

This is a DQFN (dual-row quad-flat no-leads) package.

The best (and maybe the only way) way of solder a replacement is to send the device to a qualified professional. This is not a simple task, requires specific equipments and a lot of experience.

Comment: I wouldn’t say the only way, but @mguima gives good advice. You will need solder paste, a reflow oven, and experience with stuff like this.  If you can afford the money and time to ruin the chip or PCB altogether, then give it a try. But if you actually need this done right, send it to a professional.

Comment: Not an oven, no.   But probably a stencil (which will be a pain with the board populated) or paste printer.  Unlike a normal QFN the inside pads mean you can't give it your best and then fix the issues one by one.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I have the necessary requirement to solder it (reflow station, IR PCB heater, ect). I was leaning towards DQFN but there's only 2 lots of dual row pads and the pitch is different on adjacent sides, so didn't know if it was some sort of weird BGA hybrid thing. Likewise, the pads look recessed rather than being flat with the package.